# htaccess wildcard to match only numeric value

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(page-a[^/]+)/?$ /page.php?a=$1
```

the objective is to rewrite to pages like this:

```
http://www.website.com/page-a47643
```

now how can i match only strings containing NUMBERS following "page-a" ?

The problem is that the htaccess will mess up access to folder like this:

> http://www.website.com/page-about-me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
RewriteRule ^(page-a[0-9]+)/?$ /page.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`[0-9]+` will match 1 or numbers and will leave `/page-about-me/` as is.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(page-a[0-9]+)/?$ /page.php?a=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(page-a\d+)/?$ /page.php?a=$1
```

\d in Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE, as used by Apache) means "one digit". \d+ means "one or more digits".

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^page-a([0-9]+)/?$ /page.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```